# Upgrading websocket using Nginx and Daphne. Only works if I put port number in address bar

Tags: nginx, docker, port, proxypass

To start, I am not well versed in server proxies but I can get along a bit.

Here is the scenario.

I am running an app within a docker container, using django, nginx, daphne, redis on an apache server.

1. Visit the website run by apache using example.com.
2. Apache does a proxy pass to Nginx (running in a container) 80:8080 and 443:8443
3. Then Nginx passes off to Daphne to run the actual app which is running on port 8000 in the container

The site runs perfect except websocket connection return a 404 when visiting example.com
But if I visit example.com:8443 the websockets work as expected.

I tried passing the port number along with the proxy pass but it never seems to make it in the request headers.

I just really need to know where to look to figure this out. Is it an Apache, Nginx or Daphne issue?

I have tried so many things it's not worth listing at the moment.  I am hoping the fact that the websockets work when I put the port number in the address bar is a clue.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update**

Apache directive to pass to Nginx

```
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    ProxyPass        "/" "https://localhost:8443/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://localhost:8443/"
```

Nginx config

```
upstream app {
    server app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name secret.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name secret.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/srv1.videsignz.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/private/srv1.videsignz.com.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://app;

        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/srv1.videsignz.com.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/private/srv1.videsignz.com.key;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

Docker Compose File

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    volumes:
      - assets:/assets
    image: videsignz/ktech:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - assets:/assets
      - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /etc/ssl/private:/etc/nginx/private
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8443:443"
    depends_on:
      - app
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  assets:
```

Entry Point File

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 core.asgi:application
```

Full Apache Virtual Host Config port 80 and Port 443

```
<VirtualHost 198.46.134.221:80>
  ServerName connect.ktechonline.com
    ServerAlias mail.connect.ktechonline.com www.connect.ktechonline.com
  DocumentRoot /home/connktechonline/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@connect.ktechonline.com
  UseCanonicalName Off

  ## User connktechonline # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        <IfModule !mod_passenger.c>
          UserDir disabled
          UserDir enabled connktechonline 
        </IfModule>
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
  # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
  # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
  #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
  <IfModule include_module>
    <Directory "/home/connktechonline/public_html">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  

  <IfModule suphp_module>
    suPHP_UserGroup connktechonline connktechonline
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule suexec_module>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup connktechonline connktechonline
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid connktechonline connktechonline
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID connktechonline connktechonline
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerUser connktechonline
    PassengerGroup connktechonline
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/connktechonline/public_html/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>


    # Global DCV Rewrite Exclude
    <IfModule rewrite_module>
        RewriteOptions Inherit
    </IfModule>

        
        
            
                
                
  Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/connktechonline/connect.ktechonline.com/*.conf"


  # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
  # Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/connktechonline/connect.ktechonline.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost 198.46.134.221:443>
  ServerName connect.ktechonline.com
  ServerAlias mail.connect.ktechonline.com www.connect.ktechonline.com webmail.connect.ktechonline.com cpcontacts.connect.ktechonline.com autodiscover.connect.ktechonline.com cpcalendars.connect.ktechonline.com cpanel.connect.ktechonline.com webdisk.connect.ktechonline.com
  DocumentRoot /home/connktechonline/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@connect.ktechonline.com
  UseCanonicalName Off

  ## User connktechonline # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        <IfModule !mod_passenger.c>
          UserDir disabled
          UserDir enabled connktechonline 
        </IfModule>
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
  # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
  # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
  #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
  <IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/home/connktechonline/public_html">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  
  <Proxymatch ^https?://127\.0\.0\.1:(2082|2083|2077|2078|2079|2080|2086|2087|2095|2096)/>
       <IfModule security2_module>
          SecRuleEngine Off
       </IfModule>
  </Proxymatch>

  <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup connktechonline connktechonline
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule suexec_module>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup connktechonline connktechonline
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid connktechonline connktechonline
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID connktechonline connktechonline
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerUser connktechonline
    PassengerGroup connktechonline
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/connktechonline/public_html/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLEngine on
    
    SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/connect.ktechonline.com/combined

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    <Directory "/home/connktechonline/public_html/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>
        
        
            
                
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    ProxyPass        "/" "https://localhost:8443/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://localhost:8443/"




  # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
  # Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/connktechonline/connect.ktechonline.com/*.conf"

    <IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader set X-HTTPS 1
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =autodiscover.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =autodiscover.connect.ktechonline.com:443
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket   [nocase]

            RewriteRule ^ http://127.0.0.1/cgi-sys/autodiscover.cgi [P]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpanel.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpanel.connect.ktechonline.com:443
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket   [nocase]

            RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___proxy_subdomain_cpanel/$1 [PT]
        ProxyPass "/___proxy_subdomain_cpanel" "http://127.0.0.1:2082" max=1 retry=0
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpcalendars.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpcalendars.connect.ktechonline.com:443
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket   [nocase]

            RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___proxy_subdomain_cpcalendars/$1 [PT]
        ProxyPass "/___proxy_subdomain_cpcalendars" "http://127.0.0.1:2079" max=1 retry=0
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpcontacts.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpcontacts.connect.ktechonline.com:443
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket   [nocase]

            RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___proxy_subdomain_cpcontacts/$1 [PT]
        ProxyPass "/___proxy_subdomain_cpcontacts" "http://127.0.0.1:2079" max=1 retry=0
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webdisk.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webdisk.connect.ktechonline.com:443
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket   [nocase]

            RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___proxy_subdomain_webdisk/$1 [PT]
        ProxyPass "/___proxy_subdomain_webdisk" "http://127.0.0.1:2077" max=1 retry=0
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.connect.ktechonline.com:443
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket   [nocase]

            RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___proxy_subdomain_webmail/$1 [PT]
        ProxyPass "/___proxy_subdomain_webmail" "http://127.0.0.1:2095" max=1 retry=0

                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket   [nocase]
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpanel.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cpanel.connect.ktechonline.com:443

                RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___proxy_subdomain_ws_cpanel/$1 [PT]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket   [nocase]
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.connect.ktechonline.com [OR]
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.connect.ktechonline.com:443

                RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___proxy_subdomain_ws_webmail/$1 [PT]

    RewriteRule ^/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync /___proxy_activesync/$1 [PT]
    ProxyPass "/___proxy_activesync" "http://127.0.0.1:2090/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync" max=1 retry=0
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton Updated. Like I said, the site works perfect in regards to being served. Just the websocket connections fail unless I add the port numbers to the url.

Comment: You don't show the Apache config responsible for 80 -> 8080.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Added it to the end. It is an auto generated file.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot support cPanel systems. You can try to get help from cPanel support.

Comment: I still don't see where Apache is handling connections on port 80.

Comment: Here you go @GerardH.Pille Added it. My biggest problem is that when I perform the proxy pass, it breaks webmail.connect.ktechonline.com and mail.connect.ktechonline.com.  I am not sure how to perform the proxypass only on the connect.ktechonline.com.

Comment: There is no proxypass in what you added. A selective proxypass could be a rewriterule with P-flag preceded by rewritecond testing the FQDN. Plenty of those in the 443 config.