# Apache ProxyPass adding Port only on base URL

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, port, apache2, proxypass

This is getting frustrating to say the least haha.

I have setup a proxypass and proxypassreverse in apache under virtual host 443 to proxy to nginx running in a container on port 8443.

This is all I have set up to do this

```
CustomLog /srv/apps/ktech-connect/log/apache/custom.log combined
ErrorLog /srv/apps/ktech-connect/log/apache/errors.log

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
ProxyPass        / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
```

When I hit any url such as example.com/page it works like it should
But when I go to example.com or even example.com/ it will show a redirect from apache to example.com:8443 in the url.

I have tried adding ProxyPreserveHost but it does nothing, and a whole host of other options. I just don't understand where the redirect is coming from and the fact that it only happens when hitting the base url.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The redirect is not coming from the snippet of config that you show. It may come from anywhere, even your browser's cache.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I had set a rewrite with a redirect this morning but removed it, so maybe it is my browser cache...I will clean that up and see if that is the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Oh my, you are a genius lol...it was my browser cache. I feel like such an idiot. Answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've been there myself ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is not coming from the snippet of config that you show. It may come from anywhere, even your browser's cache.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at another open question of mine if you are bored ;) https://serverfault.com/questions/1066681/upgrading-websocket-using-nginx-and-daphne-only-works-if-i-put-port-number-in-a